# Combination of committee members

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From a group of seven persons, seven committees are
formed. Any two committees have exactly one member in common.
Each person is in exactly three committees. Then

(a) At least one committee must have more than three members.

(b) Each committee must have exactly three members.

(c) Each committee must have more than three members.

(d) Nothing can be said about the sizes of the committees.

Need a way of implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Each committee must have exactly 7 members. Let the all the members form a group: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

let $\{u,v\},\{v,w\},\{u,w\}$ be pairs of 3 committees.

Note that:

1.$\binom{3}{2}=3$, each person "helps" 3 $\{u,v\}$ pairs of committees so satisfy the condition.

2.Each person is a member in exactly 3 **different** committees, and therefor the total number of seats in the 7 committees is 21.

Note number 2, tells us that if some committee have more than 3 member, another one must have less than 3 members. So if we prove that cannot have a committee with more than 3 members, we also prove that cannot be a committee with less.

Let $w$ be the committee $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with 4 members. By note 1 each member allows 2 pairs of committees: $\{w,v\},\{w,u\}$ to have him. By question's conditions there can be no one same member in more than 2 committees,so we count each pair at least and at most one.

Thus, there are 8 committees. Contradiction.

$\blacksquare$